# HOST PARA PAGINAS XHTML

Tags: java, aplicación-web, xhtml

Buenas tardes.

Me dirigo a ustedes con la siguiente inquietud, he creado un pequeño proyecto utilizando Java Server Faces, y trabajando sobre archivos XHTML.

El problema con el que me encontrado primero, es que al subir el proyecto a 000webhost.com, me solicita mi archivo sea index.html o php.

Por lo que he estado buscando la forma de subir mi proyecto y no he visto algo cercano a la solución deseada.

Alguien que haya tenido un problema similar y me pueda orientar, recomendar algún otro web host u otro comentario lo agradeceré mucho.

Comment: tu pregunta esta basada en opiniones, por lo cual acabará cerrada.

Comment: Para que tengas mejor referencia donde buscar hosting,  JSF  usa Java como tecnología apoyándose de  Facelets y servlets, ahora debes buscar un host que soporte java web application  da una mirada aquí  --- >  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750266/cloud-platforms-where-simple-java-web-application-can-be-deployed-for-free

Comment: Te basta con un host que soporte Java y un contenedor de servlets en Java como Tomcat, Jetty, Grizzly o un servidor de aplicaciones como JBoss, Wildfly,GlassFish, etc.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios me han ayudado en lo que necesitaba, mi conclusión es dejar el web host que pensaba utilizar por que no podre implementar mi proyecto, buscando una opción como lo mencionan que me permita usar java y el servidor de aplicaciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas buscar hospedajes donde soporten java que servidor de aplicaciones estas usando por ejemplo yo hice unas pruebas en este servidor.
https://openshift.redhat.com/app/, con tomcat y (glassfish).

Te recomiendo usar un servidor privado virtual.

Comment: SoftMolina me diste una respuesta corta, clara y un ejemplo de un web host. Gracias.